# ORA-02292: integrity constraint violated - child record found

Tags: sql, oracle

When I try to delete something from the user interface of an application, I get an integrity constraint

> ORA-02292: integrity constraint (V.FK_S) violated - child record
>   found..

But I am not able to see this constraint in `all_constraints`:

```
select table_name from all_constraints where owner = 'V' and constraint_name = 'FK_S';
```

I guess I am missing something here. Any tips to search further?

Comment: did you try `select table_name from dba_constraints where owner = 'V' and constraint_name = 'FK_S'`;

Comment: What database user are you using when running the sql command?  V? If not V, does your user account have the select any dictionary system privilege or has it been assigned the select catalog role?

Comment: Looks like i dont have access to dba_constraints

Comment: Am not running the sql command as V.. may be that is why am unable to find that constraint

Comment: DBA had access to dba_constraints and i was able to get the details. Thanks everyone